# FTP: Connection Refused

Tags: linux, windows, unix, ftp

I am trying to transfer files between a Linux PC to a Windows PC. I can ftp the Linux PC with localhost

> ftp localhost

prompts for the username and password and the login is successful.

But when i try to ftp to a remote host, it says the connection refused.

> ftp XX.XX.XX.XX

Connection refused.

Am i missing any parameters needed to be set. I browsed the internet but could not find my mistake. I appreciate for any ideas.

Comment: Is port 21 open on the server and is the FTP service bound to it?